# No icon showing in Android Options menu item

Tags: android, icons, android-optionsmenu

I have created an options menu with an icon I made myself (24px x 24px) but it is not showing.

The code in my xml (located in res/menu) is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/menu_insert"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_add"
    android:title="@string/menu_insert" />
</menu>
```

The menu is created in my Activity.java file as said in the documentation:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

PS The item's title is located all the way to the left and I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation how to center it (apparently android:gravity is not done there)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think your call to `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` should be deleted, it's not necessary and seems to alter your menu.

Comment: and the question was?